# How to access complex rosmsg elements in cpp?

Tags: c++, ros-melodic, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I trying to access `osrf_gear::Order` message elements within `orderCallback` scope. The structure of the message is as following:

```
string order_id
osrf_gear/Shipment[] shipments
  string shipment_type
  string agv_id
  osrf_gear/Product[] products
    string type
    geometry_msgs/Pose pose
      geometry_msgs/Point position
        float64 x
        float64 y
        float64 z
      geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation
        float64 x
        float64 y
        float64 z
        float64 w
```

The `orderCallback` code is following:

```
void orderCallback(const osrf_gear::Order::ConstPtr &order){

    if(!empty_vector_check){
        orders.clear();
        empty_vector_check = 1;
    }

    osrf_gear::Shipment order_shipments;
    order_shipments = order->shipments;  // IDE yells that this is an invalid way to assign an osrf_gear::Shipment message type

    ROS_INFO_STREAM("order_id: " << order->order_id);
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("shipment_type: " << order_shipments);
    orders.push_back(*order);

}
```

The `osrf_gear::Shipment` message structure is as following:

```
string shipment_type
string agv_id
osrf_gear/Product[] products
  string type
  geometry_msgs/Pose pose
    geometry_msgs/Point position
      float64 x
      float64 y
      float64 z
    geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation
      float64 x
      float64 y
      float64 z
      float64 w
```

Error message while building the package:

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const _shipments_type {aka const std::vector<osrf_gear::Shipment_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<osrf_gear::Shipment_<std::allocator<void> > > >}’ to ‘const osrf_gear::Shipment_<std::allocator<void> >&’
/opt/ros/melodic/include/osrf_gear/Shipment.h:23:8:
```

My questions:

1. What would be the correct syntactical way to access the `shipment[]` msg type using the `osrf_gear::order` callback parameter?
2. I want to access the `osrf_gear::Product products` vector to know what `type` of products I have in the shipment.

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396284/how-to-access-complex-rosmsg-elements-in-cpp?/) by [abhijelly](https://answers.ros.org/users/84774/abhijelly/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2022-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`shipments` in the `order` message type is a `vector` of type `osrf_gear::Shipment`. This change solved the IDE from yelling.

Have a nice day!

---

Originally posted by [abhijelly](https://answers.ros.org/users/84774/abhijelly/) with karma: 18 on 2022-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-02-17**:\

> Have a nice day!

we can only have a nice day if you would tell us what you did to resolve your question.

**Comment by [abhijelly](https://answers.ros.org/users/84774/abhijelly/) on 2022-02-18**:
@gvdhoorn done! hope it helps everyone have a nice day